# How can I remove dead JS code sent to the browser by PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, dead-code

Well, I made a little research and decided to remove dead code with Tree Shivering, but it turned out that all JS scripts with HTML are sent by PHP to  the browser and it doesn't work with npm run build or something. I don't know how to remove dead code, if only manually. The project runs on Open Server and I can't see what is going on on my terminal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP runs serverside, the JavaScript clientside.

The JavaScript is never called by PHP. Instead, it's send to the client (the browser) together with the HTML generated by PHP. The browser executes the JavaScript.

A method like Tree Shivering, will not be able to tell you what part of the JS is not used.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, so is there any way I can remove dead code?

Comment: @thirtythreeboas Rename your Scripts like _filename.js and examine, if the functionality is still complete.

Comment: There are tools for JavaScript, but it won't be able to detect which functions are called from dynamically generated content.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148788/how-to-find-dead-code-in-a-large-react-project

Comment: @thirtythreeboas I suggest considering this question as answered and asking a new question like "How can I find dead code in generated content?", where you go into this in-depth and add some examples.